# cellForRowAtIndexPath not get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I understand that many people have asked about this on stack. However, None of these can solve my problem. I try to build a tableview programmatically and cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called. But when I drag a tableview in storyboard, everything is fine. Here is the related code.

This is the code in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil]];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationItem.title = @"发布失物招领启示";

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];

self.itemDetails = @"请输入详情";

self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

self.tableView = ({
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [tableView reloadData];
    tableView;
});

[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:campusCellIdentifier bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:campusCellIdentifier];
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:imageCellIdentifier bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:imageCellIdentifier];
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:textFieldCellIdentifier bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:textFieldCellIdentifier];

UIVisualEffectView *effectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight]];
effectView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:effectView];
self.postButton = [[AYVibrantButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:AYVibrantButtonStyleFill];
self.postButton.vibrancyEffect = nil;
self.postButton.text = @"发布";
self.postButton.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0];
self.postButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor BBTAppGlobalBlue];
self.postButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[effectView.contentView addSubview:self.postButton];

[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

//Set up constraints
CGFloat verticalInnerSpacing = 10.0f;
CGFloat buttonHeight = 50.0f;
CGFloat tabBatHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
CGFloat navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;

[self.tableView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(self.view.mas_top).offset(navigationBarHeight + 20);
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.mas_bottom).offset(-tabBatHeight - 2*verticalInnerSpacing - buttonHeight);
    make.centerX.equalTo(self.view.mas_centerX);
    make.width.equalTo(self.view.mas_width);
}];

[self.postButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make){
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.mas_bottom).offset(-tabBatHeight - verticalInnerSpacing);
    make.height.equalTo(@(buttonHeight));
    make.width.equalTo(self.view.mas_width).multipliedBy(0.55);
    make.centerX.equalTo(self.view.mas_centerX);
}];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}
```

And the ones in the protocol.
Thanks for help!

Comment: I wouldnt do it inside of the closure, thats first. Second, your table has three sections? A section is essentially a column. Thirdly is it crashing or giving you any errors?

Comment: You need to add self.tableView as a subview of self.view by saying [self.view addSubview:self.tableView]; Agree with @mihado that you shouldn't do the setup in a closure.

Comment: Well it depends on whether he originally created a UITableViewController or a UIViewController

Comment: If he did it as a tableviewcontroller then none of the above code is needed

Comment: Fair point, my apologies.

Comment: I did add tableView to the subView of self.view. I just didn't copy that line here.

Comment: I need put buttons under the tableView and UITableViewController is not suitable.

Comment: @Mihado It's neither crashing or giving me any errors. The tableView just doesn't show up.

Comment: When I wake up tomorrow I'll write you some code. Till then, goodnight

Comment: @Mihado thanks, man, good night

Comment: You said "I did add tableView to the subView of self.view. I just didn't copy that line here". You need to show us the relevant code if you want help debugging your problem. Post all the code relating to creating, setting up, and adding your table view to the view controller. You should probably post your entire viewDidLoad (possibly removing sections of code the are completely unrelated)

Comment: I'm so sorry that I didn't copy the entire viewDidLoad here. Here it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

From your viewDidLoad, as, in general, the system handles the setting of constraints for your view controller's view. The mechanism by which it does this is the autoresizing mask. When `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` the system expects constraints to be provided for it, but no constraints have been added, I'm not sure if there's a defined behavior for this instance, but it's best to avoid it by allowing the system handle the size and position of `self.view`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, if you don't add your table view as a subview of the view controller's content view then it won't try to draw itself and none of the delegate/data source methods will ever be called.

Next point: Where is the "related code" from? What method, and where in that method?

Next point:

What is with this syntax?

```
self.tableView = ({
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    tableView;
});
```

Where have you seen that syntax in use in Objective-C code? I have never seen that coding style, and I've been doing Objective-C intensively since about 2007. I gather that the braces denote a scope, and since the last thing in the scope is the expression `tableView;`, the whole scope evaluates to that variable? Ugh.

Comment: No need to ridicule him, he's new. And I've seen some authors even use that ridiculous syntax, which is where he probably got it from. Please be kind.

Comment: That "related code" is from viewDidLoad. I've made it clear in my question.

Comment: I didn't mean to ridicule. Rereading my post I see what you mean. It did come off harsh. To the OP, apologies. The code I reference is quite unconventional and I would advise against it, but I am sorry if I came off as mean.

Answer (score 0):

You Have To set datasource and delegate of UItableView to your own class.....Other wise your table view will not able to get data from your class variables.....

Follow this link to read about data source and delegation

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html

Comment: I've already done that. If I drag a tableView in the storyboard, it works just fine.

Comment: Please try this code in first block

UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[tableView reloaddata];
    tableView;

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. I think if I use masonry to set layout, I should set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO.